# ASP.NET Odata Web API CRUD Operations Not Working

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, asp.net-mvc-4, odata

I have spent a about 2 days setting up my Odata Web API project that was before a simple Asp.net mvc4 project.

But still I am not successful in operating even CRUD Operations.
It says this:

```
<m:message xml:lang="en-US">
No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:53208/odata/Product'.
</m:message>
<m:innererror>
<m:message>
No action was found on the controller 'Product' that matches the request.
</m:message>
<m:type/>
<m:stacktrace/>
</m:innererror>
```

It means its reaching the Controller but not finding actions or there is some problem in my routing settings.

I have following in my WebApiConfig:

```
config.Routes.MapODataRoute("OData","odata",GetEdmModel());
```

My getEdmModel method:

```
private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
    {
        ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<Product>("Product");
        builder.EntitySet<OfferedProduct>("OfferedProduct");


        IEdmModel model = builder.GetEdmModel();

        return model;
    }
```

My controller is like this:

```
public class ProductController : EntitySetController<Product,int>
{
    private OfferAssistantDbContext db = new OfferAssistantDbContext();
    List<Product> Products = new OfferAssistantDbContext().Products.ToList();
    // GET api/Product
    [Queryable(PageSize = 10)]
    public override IQueryable<Product> Get()
    {
        return Products.AsQueryable();
    }

    // GET api/Product/5
    public Product GetProduct([FromODataUri] int id)
    {
        return Products[id];
    }
    /// and so on... but for this time lets work only on GET operation
```

Now when I write this in my browser:

```
http://localhost:53208/odata/Product
```

it says the error I showed above..

**Please guide me where is the problem?**

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your controller needs to inherit from ODataController:

```
public class ProductController : ODataController
```

Comment: i hope the OP wasn't still waiting for an answer !

Comment: It was actually some routing settings for Odata that were missing. I have migrated to API controllers due to that complexity.